# How do I fix this transforming the stax source error in Java when using Spring-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, apache-camel, spring-ws

I am currently using Camel Spring-WS to expose my endpoint as a web service. Sometimes when I am testing the web service using SoapUI, I am getting this weird error "can't transform a source of type javax.xml.transform.stax.staxsource". However, when I restart my Jboss server(Where my project is deployed), It goes away and I get the correct response. Currently I am using the server restart as a workaround. Is there a way to get rid of this problem permanently. I don't want to face these issues in production. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXP exceptions that start getting thrown for no apparent reason and that magically disappear after a server restart are typically an indication that some code running on the application server modifies one of the system properties used by JAXP, so that the factories used by JAXP change.

In your case, this is likely caused by code that changes the `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` system property and by doing so configures a new XSLT implementation that doesn't support `StAXSource`.

Note that in a JavaEE environment, application code should never attempt to change system properties because they have JVM wide scope.

In order to confirm that this is the root cause of your problem, you could try connecting to the server using JMX in order to inspect the system properties at runtime, or you could just add some code to your application that logs the value of the relevant system property.